# Spacing using minipage in theorem environment (ntheorem)

Tags: spacing, graphics, vertical-alignment, minipage, ntheorem

Consider the following example and notice the different vertical spacings between the theorem caption and the text. Is there a way to get the same spacing when using minipage as in the case of normal text?

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}%

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont%
          ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%}
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]%
    \hfill{\normalfont(##3)}\newline}
  \theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
  \theoremindent0cm
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{mystyle}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newtheorem{test}{test}
\begin{document}
   \begin{test}
      \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
         \vspace{0cm}
         %\lipsum[40]
         test
      \begin{itemize}
      \item test
      \item test
      \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
      \vspace{0cm}
      \includegraphics[draft,height=4cm, width=5cm]{imageName}
   \end{minipage}
    \end{test}
    \begin{test}
       test
    \end{test}
\end{document}
```

[image: spacing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not fiddle with adding `\vspace{0cm}` at the start of the `minipage`, since this screws up the vertical alignment. Rather adjust the image's alignment manually:

[image]

```
\begin{document}
   \begin{test}
      \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
         test
      \begin{itemize}
      \item test
      \item test
      \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
      \null\hfill\\[-\dimexpr\baselineskip+2em\relax]
      \includegraphics[draft,height=4cm, width=5cm]{imageName}
   \end{minipage}
    \end{test}
    \begin{test}
       test
    \end{test}
\end{document}
```

I've pushed it up by roughly the same amount as seemed to be the case in your MWE. Adjust as necessary.

Comment: I don't understand why manual adjustment is the best approach. Isn't LaTeX powerful enough to allow modifying the `minipage` environment to have the expected spacing before and after it?