# Easy and robust way to vertically align text and images side by side

Tags: graphics, align, minipage

Is there any syntactically easy and robust solution of how to place a image right (or left) to a text with correct vertical alignment (and appealing horizontal spacing)?

By syntactically easy I mean it should be at least as simple as the (not working) minimal example below. Uncommenting the lines `%\hspace{1ex}` and `%  \null\hfill\\[-\dimexpr\baselineskip+0.7em\relax]` makes it work but not syntactically easy easy anymore. In particular because you need to adjust the `0.7em` manually (which may be another value in other use cases) makes it painful to use.

By robust I mean that it should also work with lists instead of text and inside of theorem environments (in particular from the `ntheorem` package); compare: [Spacing using minipage in theorem environment (ntheorem)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37948/4011)

Instead of using images it should work the same way when using `tikz` or `pstricks` pictures.

As far as I know something like `wrapfig` or `picins` is not robust in that way.

Note that I don't need that the text wraps around the image as in the packages above (but this would also be ok).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}%
%\hspace{1ex}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
%  \null\hfill\\[-\dimexpr\baselineskip+0.7em\relax]
  \includegraphics[draft,height=4cm, width=5cm]{imageName}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are using `[t]` so aligning the two `minipage` on the baseline of their top row.

In the case of the second `minipage` that is the baseline of the image.

Using `[b]` or the default `[c]` would make a more reasonable layout. If you want to use
`[t]` then the second `minpage` isn't really doing anything you could just as easily use

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}%
\includegraphics[draft,width=.4\linewidth]{imageName}
```

(don't use `height` and `width` together unless you use `keepaspectratio`)

To make that look better you need to move the baseline of the image to its top or near its top. traditionally that would be done via

```
\raisebox{-\height}{\includeimage....}
```

Although the `adjustbox` package makes this easier adding `t` and `T` alignment options to `\includegraphics`.

Note that all of this is just general considerations about aligning boxes, there is nothing specific about `minipage` or `\includegraphics`.